# How can I return the latest child of a parent table in SQL

Tags: sql, parent-child

I have a parent table "A" looking like

| Main | Status | Reference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | AA |
| 2 | 1 | AB |
| 3 | 0 | AC |
| 4 | 0 | CA |

and a child table "B" (related by 'Main') looking like

| ID | Main | C-Status | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | c | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | b | 4 |
| 3 | 2 | a | 4 |
| 4 | 2 | b | 5 |
| 5 | 2 | c | 6 |
| 6 | 3 | c | 3 |
| 7 | 4 | b | 5 |
| 8 | 4 | c | 8 |
| 9 | 4 | a | 9 |

I need to find all rows in table "A", where the latest Status in table "B" has 'C-Status' with a Value of "C" and the 'Status' in table "A" is "1"

In this example it would be 'Main' "2" (ID 5). NOT "3" (ID 6) since 'Status' is not "1"

The output I would like
"A.Main", "B.C-Status", "B.Timestamp", "A.Reference"

I've been fighting with INNER JOINS and GROUP BY all my life... I just don't get it.
This would be for MS-SQL 2017 if that helps, but I'm sure it's a simple thing and not essential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `CTE` (Common Table Expression) and generate a `RANK` per `Main` using `PARTITION BY` and ordering them by `Timestamp` descending. If this `Rank` equals 1, it means it's the latest record for that `Main`.

It might sound a bit confusing, but have a look if you only run the SQL in the `WITH` statement.

Then use this rank in the `WHERE` statement to only look at the latest `C-status` per `Main`

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
       B.ID, 
       B.Main,
       B.C-Status, 
       B.Timestamp, 
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY B.Main ORDER BY B.Timestamp DESC) AS Rank
    FROM B
) 

SELECT 
   A.Main, 
   CTE.C-Status, 
   CTE.Timestamp, 
   A.Reference
FROM A
INNER JOIN CTE
ON A.ID = CTE.Main
WHERE A.Status = 1
AND   CTE.Rank = 1
AND   CTE.C-Status = 'c'
```

Also if you struggle with `JOINS` this little picture always helps: [image]

Comment: This doesn't return rows where the "last" status is "c" but rather any Main has status "c" somewhere in child.
Thx for the picture though, that will help me in future for sure.

Comment: Ah, misinterpreted your question. That does make it a tad more complex. I changed my answer so it only looks at the latest C-Status. Hope it works for you.

Comment: You're a magician!!! Works absolutely perfect! Thx so so much... I never would have come up with that!

Comment: Good to hear! Please accept the answer to help others find it in case they have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using auto-increment `id`'s (the last record automatically is the most recent one), you can use `ORDER BY id DESC` and `LIMIT 1`. Basically, you will retrieve all rows in decreasing order (latest first) and retrieve only the first one thanks to the `LIMIT`. Hope I understood the problem!

Comment: Sounds like a good idea! But what would the SQL look like; that where I struggle :(

Comment: i see. basically you just only have to add those order by and limit clauses at the end of the query. It would take me some time to understand and replicate the case on my own, but i think the other reply should do the trick. try combining both VvdL and my answers!